# MS Excel, G Sheet, count multiple condition with OR logic

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas, countif, multiple-conditions

Says I have some data, and I would like to count if it was "CC" **or** "DD". Here's what I did in Microsoft Excel and Google Sheet.

```
=sum(countifs(A2:A10, {"CC", "DD"}))
```

In MS Excel, it seems ok, but not in G Sheet.

I have to do this in G Sheet to get same result:

```
=countif(A2:A10, "CC") + =countif(A2:A10, "DD")
```

Any smarter way to do this in G Sheet ?

My sample :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array formula.

In Google Sheets: `=arrayformula(sum(countifs(A2:A10, {"CC", "DD"})))`

[image]
In older versions of Excel, you would have had to confirm this with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. It is also an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

use in Google Sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "CC|DD"), 1, )))
```